# What is the easiest way to get Twitter Bootstrap to work here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using rails 3.0.12 and would like to utilize Twitter Bootstrap's Jquery dropdown menu

Would it be best to upgrade my app to Rails 3.1 or to the newest version of Rails?

Comment: For fear of over-generalizing...Bootstrap is client side, has nothing to do with Rails so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As Terry said, Bootstrap is a client side Framework and shouldn't have anything to do with your version of Rails.

However, you may want to use directly a gem to have bootstrap directly integrated into your generated scaffold, like this one for instance :

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

In that case you may rely on which version the gem is currently supporting and make your choice from here. **It's not what I would recommend though, as you will have less control on your application UI than if you integrated Bootstrap yourself.**